# custom slide to reveal toolbar

Tags: iphone, slider, toolbar, slide, unlock

i want to do a custom toolbar, something like the slide to unlock of android phones. In idle state, the user can see a button of the bottom left of the page. the user would then tap it, drag towards the right. When the user reaches the right end, the toolbar will then 'lock'. Buttons would be located at the toolbar.

I'm think of using a customview and touchmoved functions, but what I don't know how is how to make the view move with the touch, and how to actually lock the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you move your finger the touchmoved function is called. In the touchmoved function you have to redraw the whole view or just set a new frame for this view. It pretty simple as you already know how to detect touches and react on them.